# How to filter internet access for children to limit them to a whitelist and a time range?

Tags: windows, android, iphone-app, parental-control

Scenario:

- Windows laptops, android phones, and iPhone phones.
- Users are school kids aged greater than 6, but less than 18.
- Parents are too busy to run a server.

Goal:

- Internet access timing to be limited to a maximum number of hours (e.g. total 3 hours), within defined hour ranges (e.g. from 8AM to 5PM).
- Internet access content to be limited only to certain whitelisted websites that their fitness is approved for children's age group.

Question:

- How to achieve the goal?

Comment: Some of the answers here may help you: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/computer-time-monitor-for-children

Answer (score 1):

For windows there are the parental controll settings. Android also has this for some time, so you do not need a latest version. Iphones most probably also have this settings too.

Just visit the settings of their devices and configure it there. The settings might be slightly different, alt least for iphone.

Comment: Just checked, and iphone also has parental controll

Comment: Android has parental control for websites?  For all browsers?

Comment: Android's is for their app market only.  Not for websites that you visit by web browser.  Right?  If so then it's pointless.